# How to get php-cgi with phpbrew (PHP5.3.x)

Tags: compiling, php5, cgi

I installed php-5.6.40  php-7.1.14 with phpbrew and I've got php-cgi binaries on these both version. I used this command for get php-cgi 5.6.40

```
phpbrew install 5.6.40 +default+fpm+mysql+sqlite+mb+iconv+json+iconv+exif+fileinfo +curl=/opt/CURL/curl-7.26.0 +openssl=/opt/OpenSSL/openssl-1.0.1u
```

and I get

```
~# /opt/phpbrew/php/php-5.6.40/bin/php-cgi -v
PHP 5.6.40 (cgi-fcgi) (built: Jan 14 2019 12:19:43)
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
```

On the same system, I'm trying to do the same with an old version with this command

```
phpbrew install --old 5.3.29 +default+fpm+cgi+cli+mysql+sqlite+mb+iconv+json+iconv+exif+fileinfo  +curl=/opt/CURL/curl-7.26.0 +openssl=/opt/OpenSSL/openssl-1.0.1u -- --enable-cgi
```

The compilation has been finished without error but php-cgi is not present in the bin directory of php version 5.3.29

Comment: Php5.3 is a fossil. Are you sure you want to have many troubles with it?

Comment: My question should be is php5.3.x managing php as cgi mode instead php-cgi binary

Answer (score 0):

This command installs php-cgi

```
phpbrew install --old 5.3.29 +default+openssl=/opt/OpenSSL/openssl-1.0.1u
```

Without error That's odd because when I try to force the variants I don't have php-cgi. Anyway I've got the issue. It's working with PHP 5.3.7 too